# Run sequence of kernels in loop in OpenCL

Tags: opencl

I'm programming molecular dynamics simulation which is basically loop composed mostly of calls to two kernels 1. `kernel_evalForce()` and 2. `kernel_updatePosition()`. Between these calls must be global memory synchronization which makes sure that forces are up-to-date for all threads.

```
for( int i=0; i<nMaxIter; i++ ){
   kernel_evalForce();
   // global memory must be synchronized before we proceed
   force_residual = kernell_reduceForce();
   if(force_residual < force_converged) break;
   kernel_updatePosition();
}
```

**Is there a way how to enque whole loop** composed of n repeated calls to these kernels rather than enque each call to each kernell individually?

My motivation is to minimize the overhead of CPU-GPU communication since I expect execution time of each individual kernel to be rather small.

Alternatively I was thinking to write the whole loop inside one big kernel.

```
_kernell( atom_pos, atom_forces ){
   // paraelization over atoms, each tread takes care of one atom
   const int iG = get_global_id (0);  
   for( int i=0; i<nMaxIter; i++ ){
      atom_forces[iG] = evalForce(atom_pos);
      CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE;
      force_residual = reduce_force(atom_forces);
      dt = chooseTimeStep(force_residual);
      if(force_residual < force_converged) break;
      CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE;      
      atom_forces[iG] = updatePosition( dt, atom_pos, atom_forces ); 
   }
}
```

but I think this may be problem because assuming there is much more atoms than GPU-cores, `CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE` may block to proceed processing atoms further? Or maybe I don't exactly know what is `CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE` waiting for ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enqueue each separate kernel call in a loop. There is no way to enqueue N kernel calls at once. The enqueueing itself is non-blocking, so you can enqueue multiple kernel calls in a loop while the first kernel is already running. There is very little overhead with this approach. Don't forget to finish the queue afterwards.

The second approach with the loop in the kernel does not work. barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE) is not a global synchronisation barrier across all workgroups; it only synchronizes global memory access within each inividual workgroup. For global synchronization, you need separate kernel calls.

The main source of CPU-GPU overhead is not kernel calls, but copying memory between host and device. Avoid that if possible. If global range is tiny, there can be overhead with the kernels too, when the last set of workgroups does not saturate the GPU.